# Tempi and Metronome

Tags: theory, violin

i was trying to find a web page giving some indications on the correspondence between tempi in music and the metronome value. I am playing on violin in a small orchestra and we are working on the work of Mussorgskij, Pictures from an Exhibition. I want to go prepared in the rehearsals, so i would need to know which tempo should i set the metronome at home. For example the tempo: allegro giusto, nel modo russico, senza allegrezza...to mention only one.

Can anybody give an indication of a Website or other resource which gives a correspondence of all tempi with metronome values.

Thanks for any comment.

Comment: I doubt whether you will find a list - certainly not with unusual entries like "nel modo russico." Some of the lists that are on the web don't bear much relation to the actual tempi used, and the same indication meant different tempi at different times in history. You would be better listening to some recordings of the piece - there must be some on YouTube.

Comment: Those words, and others, are only a vague tempo guide. + or - 10% minimum. A far better idea is to actually ask the conductor for his preferred timing, which he should be able to give you, in b.p.m. Even then, there will be pushes and pulls in his interpretation of a piece - even varying slightly at the actual performance.

Answer (score 1):

You'll find one on many metronomes!   But it's only a very general guide and, apart from 'allegro giusto', none of your examples are really tempo indications at all.

[image]

Comment: Aha! So THAT's where "Andante = 80-108" comes from! I can't think of *anything* marked Andante where 108 is remotely sensible - 80 should be the top of the Andante range not the bottom, IMO.